# Adding an 'active' class to a category

Tags: categories

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="News" style="nested"}

    <a href="{path='news/show/'}">{category_name}</a>              

{/exp:channel:categories}
```

This code generates a nav unordered list of all the categories.

The categories are: News, Video, Press Releases. When users are on the 'news' page how do I give that category  an 'active' class in the nav so user understand they are on that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using category URL titles in your URL, like http://domain.com/category/news, then you can simply add a conditional within the loop like this:

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="News" style="nested"}

    <a href="{path='news/show/'}" {if segment_2 == category_url_title}class="active"{/if} >{category_name}</a>              

{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the `exp:channel:categories` in dynamic mode, no matter if using [category_name](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/global_channel_preferences.html#use-category-url-titles-in-links) on URL or category ID, you can use the [`{if active}` conditional](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/categories.html#conditional-variables):

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="News" style="nested"}
    <a href="{path='news/show/'}" {if active} class="active"{/if}>{category_name}</a>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

If you are not on dynamic mode **or** you're using [Low Seg2Cat](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat), you can use this:

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="News" style="nested"}
    <a href="{path='news/show/'}" {if segment_X == category_url_title} class="active"{/if}>{category_name}</a>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Replace `segment_X` by the segment related to your category.

Or you can set one class to every category and to the HTML or BODY element and use just CSS and child selector.

Comment: Just fyi, Low Seg2Cat wouldn't be needed to access the segment_X variable, those are in the core.

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought the "or" made it clear. Feel free to improve my answer.